# What is the id( ) function used for?

Tags: python

I read [the Python 2 docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) and noticed the `id()` function:

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.
>
> CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory.

So, I experimented by using `id()` with a list:

```
>>> list = [1,2,3]
>>> id(list[0])
31186196
>>> id(list[1])
31907092 // increased by 896
>>> id(list[2])
31907080 // decreased by 12
```

What is the integer returned from the function? Is it synonymous to memory addresses in C? If so, why doesn't the integer correspond to the size of the data type?

When is `id()` used in practice?

Comment: Just because you store (say) a 32bit int in a data structure in a scripting language doesn't mean you'll be using up 32bits more memory. there's ALWAYS metadata attached to ANY data you store. type, size, length, blah blah blah.

Comment: cpython allocates from a heap that gets scrambled up as objects are malloc'd and free'd.

Comment: Python numbers are not simple pieces of data. They are objects that use longs internally to begin with, then auto-promote to a BigNumber-style representation if the value gets too large.

Comment: Possibly useful: [Drastically Improve Your Python: Understanding Python's Execution Model](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/02/14/drastically-improve-your-python-understanding-pythons-execution-model/)

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Your post asks several questions:

> What is the number returned from the function?

It is "*an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime.*" [(Python Standard Library - Built-in Functions)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) A unique number. Nothing more, and nothing less. Think of it as a social-security number or employee id number for Python objects.

> Is it the same with memory addresses in C?

Conceptually, yes, in that they are both guaranteed to be unique in their universe during their lifetime. And in one particular implementation of Python, it actually is the memory address of the corresponding C object.

> If yes, why doesn't the number increase instantly by the size of the data type (I assume that it would be int)?

Because a list is not an array, and a list element is a reference, not an object.

> When do we really use `id( )` function?

Hardly ever. You can test if two references are the same by comparing their ids, but the [`is` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#is) has always been the recommended way of doing that. `id( )` is only really useful in debugging situations.

Comment: We use id() usually in demonstration purpose like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm

Comment: Think of it as a social security number, except when the person dies it can be re-used

Answer (score 57):

That's the identity of the **location** of the object in memory...

This example might help you understand the concept a little more.

```
foo = 1
bar = foo
baz = bar
fii = 1

print id(foo)
print id(bar)
print id(baz)
print id(fii)

> 1532352
> 1532352
> 1532352
> 1532352
```

These all point to the same location in memory, which is why their values are the same. In the example, `1` is only stored once, and anything else pointing to `1` will reference that memory location.

Comment: But if you use numbers beyond the range of -5 to 256, you won't get the same id for fii variable.

Comment: that's extremely interesting. Can you share more?

Comment: I think this answer is misleading since this doesn't hold true for most numbers; see [“is” operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers).

Answer (score 12):

Rob's answer (most voted above) is correct. I would like to add that in some situations using IDs is useful as it allows for comparison of objects and finding which objects refer to your objects.

The later usually helps you for example to debug strange bugs where mutable objects are passed as parameter to say classes and are assigned to local vars in a class. Mutating those objects will mutate vars in a class. This manifests itself in strange behavior where multiple things change at the same time.

Recently I had this problem with a Python/Tkinter app where editing text in one text entry field changed the text in another as I typed :)

Here is an example on how you might use function id() to trace where those references are. By all means this is not a solution covering all possible cases, but you get the idea. Again IDs are used in the background and user does not see them:

```
class democlass:
    classvar = 24

    def __init__(self, var):
        self.instancevar1 = var
        self.instancevar2 = 42

    def whoreferencesmylocalvars(self, fromwhere):
        return {__l__: {__g__
                    for __g__ in fromwhere
                        if not callable(__g__) and id(eval(__g__)) == id(getattr(self,__l__))
                    }
                for __l__ in dir(self)
                    if not callable(getattr(self, __l__)) and __l__[-1] != '_'
                }

    def whoreferencesthisclassinstance(self, fromwhere):
        return {__g__
                    for __g__ in fromwhere
                        if not callable(__g__) and id(eval(__g__)) == id(self)
                }

a = [1,2,3,4]
b = a
c = b
democlassinstance = democlass(a)
d = democlassinstance
e = d
f = democlassinstance.classvar
g = democlassinstance.instancevar2

print( 'My class instance is of', type(democlassinstance), 'type.')
print( 'My instance vars are referenced by:', democlassinstance.whoreferencesmylocalvars(globals()) )
print( 'My class instance is referenced by:', democlassinstance.whoreferencesthisclassinstance(globals()) )
```

OUTPUT:

```
My class instance is of <class '__main__.democlass'> type.
My instance vars are referenced by: {'instancevar2': {'g'}, 'classvar': {'f'}, 'instancevar1': {'a', 'c', 'b'}}
My class instance is referenced by: {'e', 'd', 'democlassinstance'}
```

Underscores in variable names are used to prevent name colisions. Functions use "fromwhere" argument so that you can let them know where to start searching for references. This argument is filled by a function that lists all names in a given namespace. Globals() is one such function.

Answer (score 10):

`id()` does return the address of the object being referenced (in CPython), but your confusion comes from the fact that python lists are very different from C arrays. In a python list, every element is a *reference*. So what you are doing is much more similar to this C code:

```
int *arr[3];
arr[0] = malloc(sizeof(int));
*arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = malloc(sizeof(int));
*arr[1] = 2;
arr[2] = malloc(sizeof(int));
*arr[2] = 3;
printf("%p %p %p", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
```

In other words, you are printing the address from the reference and *not* an address relative to where your list is stored.

In my case, I have found the `id()` function handy for creating opaque handles to return to C code when calling `python` from C. Doing that, you can easily use a dictionary to look up the object from its handle and it's guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 5):

I am starting out with python and I use id when I use the interactive shell to see whether my variables are assigned to the same thing or if they just look the same.

Every value is an id, which is a unique number related to where it is stored in the memory of the computer.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using python 3.4.1 then you get a different answer to your question.

```
list = [1,2,3]
id(list[0])
id(list[1])
id(list[2])
```

returns:

```
1705950792   
1705950808  # increased by 16   
1705950824  # increased by 16
```

The integers `-5` to `256` have a constant id, and on finding it multiple times its id does not change, unlike all other numbers before or after it that have different id's every time you find it.
The numbers from `-5` to `256` have id's in increasing order and differ by `16`.

The number returned by `id()` function is a unique id given to each item stored in memory and it is analogy wise the same as the memory location in C.

Answer (score 4):

The `is` operator uses it to check whether two objects are identical (as opposed to equal). The actual value that is returned from `id()` is pretty much never used for anything because it doesn't really have a meaning, and it's platform-dependent.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is pretty much never. IDs are mainly used internally to Python.

The average Python programmer will probably never need to use `id()` in their code.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not average, but I use `id()` quite a bit. Two use cases off the top of my head: A (hand-rolled, ad-hoc) identity dict and a custom `repr()` for an object where identity matters but the default `repr` is not appropriate.

Comment: @delnan I wouldn't argue those are common cases.

Answer (score 2):

It is the address of the object in memory, exactly as the doc says. However, it has metadata attached to it, properties of the object and location in the memory is needed to store the metadata. So, when you create your variable called list, you also create metadata for the list and its elements.

So, unless you an absolute guru in the language you can't determine the id of the next element of your list based on the previous element, because you don't know what the language allocates along with the elements.

Comment: Actually, being a Python guru won't be of much use predicting any object's `id()`. You'd need to be intimately familiar with the memory managers (plural!) in question, know their exact state at some point in time, and know the exact order in which the objects have been allocated. In other words: Not gonna happen.

Comment: You are an absolute Python guru if you absolutely know all its nuances, including the possible memory managers.

Comment: Knowing Python and knowing a particular implementation (e.g. CPython) are two entirely different things. And even knowing CPython inside out won't help, as there are *several* memory managers CPython calls upon that aren't part of CPython but part of the respective operating system. And as I've said before, even knowing all these non-Python things won't help you, as the actual addresses depend on the run-time state of the memory managers, and are sometimes even randomized.

Comment: Not to mention, it would be useless to know, as relying on such a thing would be relying upon an implementation detail and hence be fragile and inflexible.

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea to use value of `id()` in logging.
It's cheap to get and it's quite short.
In my case I use tornado and `id()` would like to have an anchor to group messages scattered and mixed over file by web socket.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little bit late and i will talk about Python3. To understand what id() is and how it (and Python) works, consider next example:

```
>>> x=1000
>>> y=1000
>>> id(x)==id(y)
False
>>> id(x)
4312240944
>>> id(y)
4312240912
>>> id(1000)
4312241104
>>> x=1000
>>> id(x)
4312241104
>>> y=1000
>>> id(y)
4312241200
```

You need to think about everything on the right side as objects. Every time you make assignment - you create new object and that means new id. In the middle you can see a "wild" object which is created only for function - id(1000). So, it's lifetime is only for that line of code. If you check the next line - you see that when we create new variable x, it has the same id as that wild object. Pretty much it works like memory address.

Answer (score 0):

As of in python 3 id is assigned to a value not a variable. This means that if you create two functions as below, all the three id's are the same.

```
>>> def xyz():
...     q=123
...     print(id(q))
...
>>> def iop():
...     w=123
...     print(id(w))
>>> xyz()
1650376736
>>> iop()
1650376736
>>> id(123)
1650376736
```

Comment: Even though this contradicts previous explanations it seems to happen and I don't know why. Any explanation? For instance x[0] = "abc" x[1]="def" q=["abc", "def"]. Id(x) == Id(q)  is True. Coincidence?

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull (concerning the answer just below)...That's only true because 123 is between -5 and 256...

```
In [111]: q = 257                                                         

In [112]: id(q)                                                            
Out[112]: 140020248465168

In [113]: w = 257                                                         

In [114]: id(w)                                                           
Out[114]: 140020274622544

In [115]: id(257)                                                         
Out[115]: 140020274622768
```