# Why id() in python also returns a value for literal

Tags: python-3.x

I just started studying Python and came across id() builtin method.
I found that it returns a value even for id("sudgfkasdfgalds9834710931934019734216834jefhdkdj").

As per my understanding from Python tutorials and also from [What does id( ) function used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667189/what-does-id-function-used-for), id() returns a memory address. So why a memory address is being returned for any random value which is not even assigned to any variable.

Comment: Because literals have a memory address in which they are stored.

Answer (score 4):

The nature of Python is different from that of languages like C, where a variable is more-or-less a memory location.

In Python, a variable assignment can be thought of assigning a label to an object. Objects that have no labels referencing them are eventually reclaimed by the garbage collector. Multiple labels can point to the same object.

Look at the following:

```
In [1]: a = 1

In [2]: b = 1

In [3]: id(a), id(b)
Out[3]: (34377130320, 34377130320)
```

Both `a` and `b` reference the same object.

Note that in Python some type of objects (like numbers and strings) are *immutable*. You cannot change their instances. See:

```
In [4]: a += 1

In [5]: id(a)
Out[5]: 34377130352
```

After incementing, `a` points to a *different object*.

As an aside, when CPython starts, it creates objects for often-used small integers (like 0-100). These objects are significantly bigger than what you would normally associate with an integer. Also note that using memory addresses as `id` is a CPython implementation detail. So in CPython we can do:

```
In [6]: id(2) - id(1)
Out[6]: 32

In [7]: (id(100) - id(0))/32
Out[7]: 100.0
```

So in this case (64-bit FreeBSD OS, CPython 3.6) an integer object is 32 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

It returns the actual `id` of the argument that you have called. I mean, if you call `id('c')` it will return different values every time you try to call it.