# Why does a variable in Python return to former ID after converting back and forth?

Tags: python, variables

Could someone explain why my variable x returns to it's former ID after these steps:

```
>>> x = 10
>>> id(x)
497834400
>>> x = str(x)
>>> id(x)
48840576
>>> x = int(x)
>>> id(x)
497834400
```

Comment: The value of `x` before and after the conversion is the same number 10. That's why it has the same id.

Comment: @DYZ that is not generally true for objects, though, and only happens to be true on CPython for ints between -5 and 256

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I did not generalize to _objects_, I only made a claim for the number 10. I agree with the rest of your remark.

Comment: But this doesn't even generalize to all `int` objects, for example, it doesn't work for `a = 1000; b = 1000` I'm just saying your statement is misleading without a little more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python caches the integers from `[-5, 256]`, which means that (during the same runtime) a integer in the above range will always have the same `id`.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171695/weird-integer-cache-inside-python) and it's great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15172182/758165) for more detail.

Comment: Very interesting. After testing with x = 300 the ID did in fact change.

Answer (score 1):

Because 10 is something called small-integer in python. Python will cache the small-integer between [-5，257）in a pool called "small_ints".  So the instance of integer in  [-5，257） are all shared in whole python, that's why id(10) always return the same address.

Answer (score 0):

```
What is the number returned from the function id() ?
```

It is "an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime." (Python Standard Library - Built-in Functions) A unique number. Nothing more, and nothing less. Think of it as a social-security number or employee id number for Python objects.

```
Is it the same with memory addresses in C ?
```

Conceptually, yes, in that they are both guaranteed to be unique in their universe during their lifetime. And in one particular implementation of Python, it actually is the memory address of the corresponding C object.

[what-does-id-function-used-for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667189/what-does-id-function-used-for)

Answer (score -2):

The int data type of the variable is available during lifetime and lifetime of x is not finished yet.
In fact it points back to int type of x by converting back x to int.