# Python: Memory Model ID

Tags: python

Does the order in which you enter things into Python affect the ID of that object?
(ie. if I first type s = list1, then s2 = list2, will the ID of s be 1 and the ID of s2 be 2?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id of an object is its memory location. There is no guarantee about where in memory something will be stored, or whether a newer object will stored at a "higher" address.

For example, let's say we make an object `a`, then `b`. Then we remove and garbage collect `a` and make a new object `c`. This new object `c` might just be stored in `a`'s old location. Or not. There is no real way of knowing. It's all handled by the python memory manager which does things in such a way that the user cannot really know where a new object will end up.

So in general, the answer to your question is "no".

For more info see the following post: [What is the id( ) function used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667189/what-is-the-id-function-used-for/15667328)