# Where in memory is a variable assignment stored?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, memory-management

```
y=5
id(5)
id(y)
```

In cpython  the two id commands will return the same memory adddress, where the integer 5 is stored, but where in memory is  the                                                                                                               information           that                              y **is equal to**   5               stored?

why      is it important to be able to know where 5 is stored in memory, but not      important to       know                      where    in   memory                         y is              equal to  5    is stored?

Also, is it possible to store the number 5 in more than one place in memory when using python?  why or why not?

Comment: Please read https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the id( ) function used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667189/what-is-the-id-function-used-for)

Comment: In Python (the language) it is of no importance where any object or reference is stored in memory. The address is just used to have a safe hash value.

Answer (score 4):

`id(y)` and `id(5)` say where the `5` in question is stored, not where `y` itself (the name) is stored.

The location of `y` itself (the name holding the pointer to the object representing `5`) is an implementation detail; in CPython, function local names are stored in an array created when the function is called and cleaned when the function finishes, while global names are stored in a per-module `dict` (visible as `globals()`). The `__code__` attribute of functions contains information about the locals, but doesn't provide direct access to the array (because that would allow Python code to break interpreter invariants, or take dependencies on implementation details that could change even between micro releases).

Knowing where `5` is isn't really important. The `id` function isn't intended to provide actual locations, that's just a convenient way to assign unique IDs that CPython uses. In non-CPython interpreters like PyPy, it doesn't actually have to describe a memory address at all (they assign unique IDs in other ways, because garbage collection means memory addresses aren't stable over the lifetime of an object). The point of the `id` is about identity; are these two things the *same* object (also testable with the `is` operator), not just equal in value.

As to your question "is it possible to store the number 5 in more than one place in memory when using python?", the answer for CPython is "No", but the language spec makes no such guarantee. `id(y)` and `id(5)` are the same only because of an implementation detail, the small `int` cache. On CPython, `int`s from `-5` to `256` (inclusive) are singletons; no matter how you get them (math, parsing strings, literals, etc.) there is only one of each. But for `int`s outside that range, they're created on demand, so the `id`s won't overlap in most cases:

```
>>> y = 500
>>> id(y)
2538476592176
>>> id(500)
2538471826288
```