# Python list I don't know why the difference is 16

Tags: python

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.getsizeof(int()))
12
>>> print(sys.getsizeof(str()))
25
>>> mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,'ab']
>>> print(id(mylist))
50204144
>>> print(id(mylist[0]))
1849873456
>>> print(id(mylist[1]))
1849873472
>>> print(id(mylist[2]))
1849873488
>>> print(id(mylist[3]))
1849873504
>>> print(id(mylist[4]))
1849873520
>>> print(id(mylist[5]))
50209152
```

I don't know why the difference is 16:

64-bit operating system

Comment: Please do NOT post images of your code. Instead, post directly your code in code format (Ctr+K).

Comment: output is   12
25
50204144
1849873456
1849873472
1849873488
1849873504
1849873520
50209152

Comment: For the love of programming edit your post and put all of this inside it.

Comment: This is an implementation detail of CPython.

Comment: Please update your post to enter the code instead of an image

Comment: it would be better if you put your code here and not pasting the screenshot. Describe what exactly you wanted and what you are getting. You can refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why do you care about the distance anyway? It's an implementation detail, completely unspecified and arbitrary. The difference is what it is because, well, that's how CPython was written.

Comment: help(id)
Help on built-in function id in module builtins:

id(obj, /)
    Return the identity of an object.
    
    This is guaranteed to be unique among simultaneously existing objects.
    (CPython uses the object's memory address.)

Comment: Thank you. I just used Print (help (id)

Answer (score 1):

Because they are **int** inside a list the location in memory of a integer goes **16 to 16** bits I truly recommend you to see this post: [What is the id( ) function used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667189/what-is-the-id-function-used-for)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your question is: *If `sys.getsizeof(int())` is 12, then why are some of the the `id()` values 16 bytes apart instead of 12?*

And it looks like you are expecting newly allocated `int`s to be 12 bytes away from one another because an `int` takes 12 bytes of storage.

If you are expecting that, it is because you are expecting a Python list to be like a C array, a chunk of contiguous memory where an array of five 8-byte objects takes exactly 40 bytes. But Python lists are not arrays, and list elements are not necessarily allocated in ascending memory order (let alone packed together). And so you can't expect the values of `id()` to be predictable from the amount of memory the object takes up.

By all means learn about the way Python's data structures are really allocated, if that really interests you. But it is a topic so advanced that few outside the CPython core team ever need to think about it. The rest of us are just content that it works. Which is why you are getting comments like *it's an implementation detail* and *why do you care?*

It is important to know how a C array is allocated because in C you manipulate memory pointers directly and getting that wrong can be catastrophic. But Python takes care of memory allocation for you, so knowing all the details of how it works is unlikely to make you a better Python programmer.