# How class level attribute values are evaluated in python?

Tags: python

I've the following class structure:

```
class StarCount:
    one_stars = 0
    two_stars = 0
    three_stars = 0
    four_stars = 0
    five_stars = 0

class OrientationAnalysis:
    straight = StarCount()
    bisexual = StarCount()
    gay = StarCount()

class GenderAnalysis:
    men = OrientationAnalysis()
    women = OrientationAnalysis()
```

I've written the following code:

```
genderanalysis = GenderAnalysis()
genderanalysis.men.straight.five_stars = 100

print genderanalysis.men.straight.five_stars # outputs 100
print genderanalysis.women.straight.five_stars # this is also 100
```

Why `genderanalysis.women.straight.five_stars` is also updated? I've checked the `genderanalysis.women.gay.five_stars` also but it's not updated?

Comment: Why are these class attributes instead of instance attributes?

Comment: @user2357112 I don't know. I'm from `java` and trying to define my data structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare some variables like this:

```py
class StarCount:
    one_stars = 0
    two_stars = 0
    three_stars = 0
    four_stars = 0
    five_stars = 0
```

These variables become `class` variables. `Class` variables are variables that are shared by all instances of a class. So when you updated `genderanalysis.men.straight.five_stars`, it actually updated `StarCount.five_stars` and as `genderanalysis.women.straight.five_stars` also points to the same variable, it seemed to have updated too.

I think what you are looking for are `instance variables`. You can declare them like this:

```py
class StarCount:
    def __init__(self):
        self.one_stars = 0
        self.two_stars = 0
        self.three_stars = 0
        self.four_stars = 0
        self.five_stars = 0
```

**Edit**

> Why `genderanalysis.women.gay.five_stars` is not updated?

What happens is that before you updated any variable of `genderanalysis` object, all of the variables were pointing to the variables of `StarCount` class. As you can see they have same [id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667189/what-is-the-id-function-used-for):

```py
print(id(StarCount.five_stars)) # prints '94016229389744'
print(id(genderanalysis.men.straight.five_stars)) # prints '94016229389744'
print(id(genderanalysis.women.gay.five_stars)) # prints '94016229389744'
```

But when you changed `genderanalysis.men.straight.five_stars`, the reference/pointer got replaced with your provided value, in this case `100`. You can see difference in their id's:

```py
print(id(StarCount.five_stars)) # prints '94016229389744'
print(id(genderanalysis.men.straight.five_stars)) # prints '94016229391328', see the difference?
```

So now `genderanalysis.men.straight.five_stars` does not point to `StarCount.five_stars`, rather it points to `OrientationAnalysis.straight.five_stars`. Once again, let's check their id's:

```py
print(id(OrientationAnalysis.straight.five_stars)) # prints '94016229391328'
print(id(genderanalysis.men.straight.five_stars)) # prints '94016229391328', same right?
```

Now onto your question, at this point `genderanalysis.women.gay.five_stars` is still untouched so it points to `StarCount.five_stars` and so it still prints `0`. Change `StarCount.five_stars` and you can see the change reflecting in `genderanalysis.women.gay.five_stars`.

```py
StarCount.five_stars = 101
print(genderanalysis.women.gay.five_stars) # prints `101`
```

Comment: Why `genderanalysis.women.gay.five_stars` is not updated? It also belongs to same class.

Comment: @Nayan I've edited my answer with some explanations. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Define the values in the init methods of the classes, so that they become attached to intance objects, not the class object itself.

```
class StarCount:
    def __init__(self):
        self.one_stars = 0
        self.two_stars = 0
        self.three_stars = 0
        self.four_stars = 0
        self.five_stars = 0

class OrientationAnalysis:
    def __init__(self):
        self.straight = StarCount()
        self.bisexual = StarCount()
        self.gay = StarCount()

class GenderAnalysis:
    def __init__(self):
        self.men = OrientationAnalysis()
        self.women = OrientationAnalysis()

genderanalysis = GenderAnalysis()
genderanalysis.men.straight.five_stars = 100

print genderanalysis.men.straight.five_stars # outputs 100
print genderanalysis.women.straight.five_stars # this is now 0
```

Answer (score 1):

your attributes should not be *class attributes* but *instance attributes* instead. this would be a start for you:

```
class StarCount:
    def __init__(self, five_stars=0):

        self.five_stars = five_stars
        # ...


class OrientationAnalysis:
    def __init__(self):

        self.straight = StarCount()
        # ...


class GenderAnalysis:
    def __init__(self):

        self.men = OrientationAnalysis()
        self.women = OrientationAnalysis()
```

Comment: In my case, why `genderanalysis.women.gay.five_stars` is not updated? They are from same class i.e `StarCount`

Comment: just tried that  (in python 3): this value is also updated...

Comment: I tried with python 2. Let me check again.

Comment: surprisingly in python 2 class attributes are not always updated. Seems there is something happening during the object creation life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

you’re almost there— you are referencing and modifying class variables rather than instance variables.

You need an `__init__(self)` method, and to create all the attributes on `self`

Comment: Why other fields e.g. `genderanalysis.women.gay.five_stars` is not affected then?