# Getting Output False p=0 i=0 print(id(p) is id(i))

Tags: python-3.x

```
p=0
i=0
print(id(p) is id(i))
```

As p and i share common memory location, Still the output of this program is False.

Kindly anyone let me know why I am getting False as the id of both p and i is same?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between "==" and "is"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is)

Comment: Integers are "identical" objects in the range of -5 to 256  - the output of `id()` is an integer NOT inside that range - so the calls to `id(p)` and `id(i)` are different objects hence not True when compared with `is`

Answer (score 0):

`p` & `i` may refer to the same object. But `id(p)` & `id(i)` are different objects.

```
p=0
i=0
print(id(p))
print(id(i))
print(id(p) is id(i))
print(id(p) == id(i))
```

Output:

```
4458376944
4458376944
False
True
```

The integers with value `4458376944` that the `id` function creates are separate objects. Specifically this is because those numbers are out of the interning range for python: ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

To compare two `id()` values you should just use the `==` operator instead.

Answer (score 0):

try using this

`print(id(p) == id(0))`

The == operator compares the values of both the operands and checks for value equality. Whereas is operator checks whether both the operands refer to the same object or not.

Answer (score -1):

For the information on id() you can refer to [What is the id( ) function used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667189/what-is-the-id-function-used-for).