# What does the hex value means when printing a method in python?

Tags: python, class, methods

just a simple and quick question that I cannot find the answer. I have this class with this method inside:

```
class Pokemon:
    "This is a pokemon class"
     number = 10

    def birth(self):
        print('Hello')

print(Pokemon.birth)
```

Output:

```
<function Pokemon.birth at 0x7fc78c6e8160>
```

When I print the method it returns a hex number, what does this hex exactly mean? memory location? I am trying to understand the process behind the code.

PD. I am not trying to make the class work, just curiosity about the hex

Thanks

Comment: In your code you missed: 1. the constructor of the class 2. creating an instance of the class 3. calling `birth()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **what does this hex exactly mean? memory location?**

Yes is the address of the object in memory. it is represented in hexadecimal number in order to make it more 'human readable.'

```
import sys

class Pokemon:
    "This is a Pokemon class"
    numner = 10

    def birth(self):
        print('Hello')


print(Pokemon)
#<class '__main__.Pokemon'>

print(Pokemon.birth)
#<function Pokemon.birth at 0x000001F83C177C10>

print(hex(id(Pokemon)))
#0x1f83bf6fad0

print(hex(id(Pokemon.birth)))
#0x1f83c177c10

print(Pokemon.birth.__repr__)
# <method-wrapper '__repr__' of function object at 0x0000018609D87C10>
```

### Interesting features

- [sys.getsizeof](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof)

Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.

```
print(sys.getsizeof(Pokemon))
print(sys.getsizeof(Pokemon.birth))
#1064
#136
```

- Reference Counts and Namespace

The code below show where the object Pokemon.birth leaves. It is not in the globals() namespace but rather within the '__main.__Pokemon' class namespace.

```
print(globals()['Pokemon'])
# <class '__main__.Pokemon'>
print(Pokemon.__dict__['birth'])
# <function Pokemon.birth at 0x0000020D51167C10>
```

- [Pointers in Python: What's the Point?](https://realpython.com/pointers-in-python/)
- [Namespaces and Scope in Python](https://realpython.com/python-namespaces-scope/)

Comment: Thanks for answering.  Most completed answer yet. I think **id()** function might be useful in hardware or mobile applications when we are really concern about the memory, but those type of applications usually requires other languages (HDL). I really don't see when this might be useful. Have you ever used that function?

Comment: @AndresMitre - `id()` can be useful when you need a unique identifier of an object for some reason, for example to keep track of whether you've already seen it while processing some complex data structure.

Comment: @andres there for sure some use in a real qord application. At the moment i only used it for debugging purposes or understand if an object is still the same after have processed. Is actually just like use the is operator ( print(a is b)) for instance function itertools.repeat(n, i) it creates an infinite 'copies' of obj i by times of n. However are really the same object. When i first used it i checked it by printing the id if each item. Finding out is the same object.

Comment: Actually here an SOO that shows a used scenario of the id function   https://stackoverflow.com/a/29087011/13903942

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, that's the memory address. You can also obtain it with the [`id()` built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id).

Comment: Oh thanks for sharing @sabik . I tested it and it returns the memory address in base-10. I couldn't find it out there. Thank you.

Comment: @AndresMitre - You can convert the address from the `id()` function to hex using either the `hex()` function or one of the integer formatting options (`%x` or `{:x}`).

Answer (score 3):

This is the memory address of the function.

You need to use parentheses when calling a function. Interpreter won't complain/crash if you don't use parentheses to call the function, it will just tell you that what you have is a function handle (i.e. the message that you got, memory address).

BTW you can get hex memory address of a function using `id()`

> ```
> Help on built-in function id in module builtins:
>
> id(obj, /)
>    Return the identity of an object.
>    
>    This is guaranteed to be unique among simultaneously existing objects.
>    (CPython uses the object's memory address.)
> ```

Comment: Thanks for answering @Wasif . I didn't know how to search that question...Have you ever required  the *id()*  function in real applications?

Comment: @AndresMitre Nope

Answer (score 1):

If you want to invoke a function you should invoke it by calling `birth()`. Your call just show the identity of `birth`

In order to make your code work you need to create an instance of your class.

`pokemon` is an instance of the class `Pokemon` so you can call `birth` which is instance method. See [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm) for more about this topic.

```
class Pokemon:
    "This is a pokemon class"
    number = 10

    def birth(self):
        print('Hello')

pokemon = Pokemon()
pokemon.birth()
```

Comment: oh maybe I was not clear @balderman. I was just wondering what was the hex number about. It turns out that it is the function id. Thanks for answering anyways

Comment: @AndresMitre I was under the impression that by the end you would like to activate `birth` so I have posted my answer :-)