# Create a new list of dict, from a dict with a key that has a list value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dict with one of the keys have a value of list

```
example = {"a":1,"b":[1,2]}
```

I am trying to unpack `example["b"]` and create a list of the same dict with separate `example["b"]` value.

```
output = [{"a":1,"b":1},{"a":1,"b":2}]
```

I have tried to use a for loop to understand the unpacking and reconstruction of the list of dict but I am seeing a strange behavior - It could be I am missing something simple here...

```
iter = example.get("b")

new_list = []

for p in iter:
    print(f"p is {p}")
    tmp_dict = example
    tmp_dict["b"] = p
    print(tmp_dict)
    new_list.append(tmp_dict)

print(new_list)
```

Output

```
p is 1
{'a': 1, 'b': 1}
p is 2
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
```

Why is the first dict in the list gets assigned with `example["b"] = 2` although the first `print()` shows that `p is 1`?

Comment: Because `tmp_dict` is the same dictionary(`example`) within the loop. There is only one dictionary instance, so last value assignment only has effect. You can use shallow copy to make different dictionary. `tmp_dict = example.copy()`

Comment: Plus, you shouldn't use `iter` as a variable name since it is a builtin name. You can avoid builtin name shadowing with trailing underscore. `iter_ = example.get("b")`.

Comment: Or you can shorten it to `new_list = [example | {'b': p} for p in example['b']]` (for python 3.9+); or `new_list = [{**example, 'b': p} for p in example['b']]` (3.5+).

Comment: Appending @j1-lee's comment, `new_list = [{**example, 'b': p} for p in example['b']]` would work in 3.8- versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the first dict in the list gets assigned with example["b"] = 2 although the first print() shows that p is 1

Because they are all the same dict: `example`. You can see this if you `print(id(tmp_dict))` inside the loop, and you'll see that it is always the same object. See [What is the id( ) function used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15667189/843953) (it's a python 2 question, but applies to python 3 as well)

If you want to keep your code, you just need to create a new dictionary from `example` and assign it to `tmp_dict`. See [How to copy a dictionary and only edit the copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465921/how-to-copy-a-dictionary-and-only-edit-the-copy)

```
tmp_dict = example.copy()
```

although that basically copies the entire dictionary only to discard the `b` key, so you could simply do:

```
tmp_dict = {"a": example["a"]}
```

Note, your use of `iter` as a variable name is not recommended, since `iter` already [means something in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter)

---

Instead, here's a general approach that works for *all* cases without hardcoding any keys.
Let's first create a temporary dictionary where all values are lists.

```
temp = {k: v if isinstance(v, list) else [v] for k, v in example.items()}
```

This allows us to then obtain the list of all the values in our `temp` dict as a list of lists.

We want the *product* of all the values of this `temp` dictionary. To do this, we can use the `itertools.product` function, and [unpack](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/packing-and-unpacking-arguments-in-python/) our list of lists to its arguments.

In each iteration, the resulting tuple will have one value per key of the `temp` dictionary, so all we need to do is [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) that with our tuple, and create a dict out of those key-value pairs. That gives us our list element!

```
import itertools

keys = list(temp.keys())
vals = list(temp.values())

result = []

for vals_product in itertools.product(*vals):
    d = dict(zip(keys, vals_product))
    result.append(d)
```

Which gives the required result:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
```

This even works for an `example` with more keys:

```
example = {'a': 1, 'b': [1, 2], 'c': [1, 2, 3]}
```

which gives:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 2},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 3},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2},
 {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one minor correction: Usage of dict()

```
example = {"a":1,"b":[1,2]}

iter = example.get("b")

new_list = []

for p in iter:
    print(f"p is {p}")
    tmp_dict = dict(example)
    tmp_dict["b"] = p
    print(tmp_dict)
    new_list.append(tmp_dict)

print(new_list)
```

Output is as given below:
[{'a': 1, 'b': 1}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]